# Python - Extracting elements from an array similar to JavaScript ES6 Destructuring

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, dictionary

With JavaScript ES6 syntax I can to set variables from array:

```
const [first, second] = names;  
console.log(first, second); // 'Luke' 'Eva'
```

Does python have a similar syntax?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can unpack lists like so:

```
myList = [1, 2, 3]
a, b, c = myList
print(a) # 1
print(b) # 2
print(c) # 3
```

Also, in javascript you can do the following:

```
// javascript:
let myArray = [1, 2, 3];
let [first, ...other] = myArray;
console.log(first); // 1
console.log(other); // [2, 3]
```

Which is also achievable in Python:

```
myList = [1, 2, 3]
first, *other = myList
print(first) # 1
print(other) # [2, 3]
```

The following is also possible:

```
myList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
a, *other, last = myList
print(a)      # 1
print(other)  # [2, 3, 4]
print(last)   # 5
```

It also works on tuples, though note that when unpacking tuples with the `*` operator, the result is a list:

```
a, b, *other = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
print(a)     # 1
print(b)     # 2
print(other) # [3, 4, 5]
```